# Docker - decrease pull size

Tags: docker

I'm using docker for our jetty application.

It has following layers:

1. global-dependencies
2. app-dependencies
3. app
4. app-config - 5 different configurations.

Each layer has previous layer in its 'FROM' line in Dockerfile.
Normally only `app` and `app-config` are changed.
If I change something in `*-dependencies` image I uncomment them in build script so they get updated.

At the end of build script I do:

```
sudo docker tag app-config-1 my_registry:5000/app-config-1:$version  
sudo docker push my_registry:5000/app-config-1
```

Then on the destination host I do:

```
docker pull my_registry:5000/app-config-1:$version
```

This setup works like a charm - when there are no changes to the `*-dependencies` images it takes only 2 minutes to create 5 images.

The problem is with pulling of the images. Even if only the `app` layer is changed, which is about 100M it seems like `pull` downloads data from all parent images, even though they were not rebuilt. I have to pull about a gigabyte of data for a small change.

Is there some mistake in my workflow? Can I somehow optimize the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try tagging intermediate steps and using them explicitly? The output of step 2, say "appdep" and then in step 3 use `FROM appdep` and then tag that output as "app" and then for the final loop of 5, use `FROM app` for each config.

Comment: > "If I change something in *-dependencies image I uncomment them in build script so they get updated."  Does the caching mechanism not take care of that got you?

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using? I think that Docker doesn't let you `docker push my-registry:5000/my-image:image-version` (it will barf on the `:image-version` part). I just tried with 0.9, and fair enough, `docker push localhost:5000/busybox:42` tells me `2014/04/04 12:50:06 Invalid repository name (busybox:42), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed`.

Comment: @jpetazzo, sorry, it was a mistake - I just looked at actual build script and it only has `sudo docker push my_registry:5000/app-config-1`

Answer (score 2):

Just for someone with a similar problem:

You can investigate changes done to the image by doing

```
docker history my_registry:5000/app-config-1
```

It will show you all the layers and the size difference after each command.

In my case I had a huge folder added in the first step (which is executed very rarely).
The problem was that in one of the later steps I had a command changing permissions on this folder. This made docker create a new layer with all the files (around 400M).

Now I change the permissions in the first step right after adding the folder, so size of the images is significantly decreased.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Now you can inspect your image & its layers visually using ImageLayers.io to help see why the extra size is.